# Boiling point of water

Tags: boiling-point

I was doing an experiment on boiling-point of water and I was supposed to measure the temperature of the water when it boils, but I saw the there were droplets of water on the lid of the pot, and I was confused if I should take the temperature of the droplets too ,then record the average temperature.

Comment: No, the droplets on the lid are irrelevant. They can be pretty far from boiling, too.

Comment: I'm kinda curious why someone downvoted this question; yeah, it's pretty ignorant, but then, as someone once said, everyone's ignorant, just on different subjects. The OP asked a question because he/she didn't have the information to know better, but to downvote just because of that seems mean.